# Is SKCropNode limited to a width below 5000?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, sprite-kit

I am trying to use a `SKCropNode` with a width of at least 5000 pixels, yet if the `maskNode` property width is greater than 4100 something strange happens -- the first 100-200 or so pixels are not cropped, and the cropping spans approx only 4100 pixels.

I'm on a Mac Mini M1, Ventura 13.0.1 and Xcode 14.1 (14B47b)

Here is the working code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var spriteView : SpriteView!
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: true) {
            ZStack {
                if spriteView != nil {
                    spriteView
                }
                VStack {
                    Image(systemName: "globe")
                        .imageScale(.large)
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    Text("Hello, world!")
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .onAppear {
                spriteView = .init(scene: myScene)
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 1000, minHeight: 500)
        }
    }
    
    var myScene : SKScene {
        let r = SKScene.init(size: .init(width: 2000, height: 500))
        r.backgroundColor = .yellow
        
        let maskRect = SKShapeNode.init(rect: .init(x: 0, y: 100, width: 5000, height: 300))
//        let maskRect = SKShapeNode.init(rect: .init(x: 0, y: 100, width: 4096+2, height: 300))
        maskRect.fillColor = .white
        maskRect.lineWidth = 0
        
        let redRect = SKShapeNode.init(rect: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 5000, height: 500)))
        redRect.fillColor = .red
        redRect.lineWidth = 0
        
        let path = CGMutablePath.init()
        path.move(to: .zero)
        path.addLine(to: .init(x: 1000, y: 500))

        let blueLine = SKShapeNode.init(path: path)
        blueLine.strokeColor = .blue
        blueLine.lineWidth = 12

        redRect.addChild(blueLine)
        
        let cropNode = SKCropNode.init()
        
        cropNode.maskNode = SKNode.init()
        cropNode.maskNode?.addChild(maskRect)
        cropNode.addChild(redRect)
        
        let blackRect = SKShapeNode.init(rect: .init(origin: .init(x: 0, y: 100), size: .init(width: 5000, height: 300)))
        blackRect.fillColor = .black
        blackRect.lineWidth = 0
        r.addChild(blackRect)
        r.addChild(cropNode)
        
        return r
    }
}
```

The result I get is
[image]

If I change the width to 4096 I get the correct result without the black rectangle on the left hand side, ie `let maskRect = SKShapeNode.init(rect: .init(x: 0, y: 100, width: 4096, height: 300))`

[image]

EDIT:

Using `SKSpriteNode` as suggested produced the same results for me:

```
        let maskRect = SKSpriteNode.init(color: .black, size: .init(width: 5000, height: 300))
        maskRect.position.x = 0 + maskRect.size.width/2
        maskRect.position.y = 100 + maskRect.size.height/2
```

Answer (score -1):

this appears to be an issue with `SKShapeNode`.

solution: use `SKSpriteNode` instead -- both for your mask and for any other large elements in the scene. here is an illustration (swap the red and green nodes to see the glitch):

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct GameSceneCrop: View {
    @State private var scene = CropScene()
    
    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
    }
}

class CropScene: SKScene {
    let skCameraNode = SKCameraNode()
    var WIDTH:CGFloat = 5000
    var HEIGHT:CGFloat = 1000
    let container = SKNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        scaleMode = .aspectFill // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        backgroundColor = .yellow
        anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)

        //set up camera node
        camera = skCameraNode
        addChild(skCameraNode)
        skCameraNode.setScale( 10000 )
        
        addChild(container)
        rebuild()
    }
    
    func rebuild() {
        container.removeAllChildren()
        
        //a green SKSpriteNode
        let green = SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: CGSize(width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT))
        
        //a red SKShapeNode
        let red = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT))
        red.fillColor = .red
        
        //crop node
        let mask = SKSpriteNode(color: .black, size: red.frame.size) //using SKSpriteNode here instead of SKShapeNode
        let crop_node = SKCropNode()
        crop_node.maskNode = mask
        crop_node.addChild(green) //<--- replace green SKSpriteNode with red SKShapeNode to see clipping glitch
        container.addChild(crop_node)

        //draw outline around red block
        let reference_frame = SKShapeNode(rect: red.frame.insetBy(dx: -50, dy: -50))
        reference_frame.strokeColor = .black
        reference_frame.lineWidth = 50
        container.addChild(reference_frame)
    }
    
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        let x = 0.65 + (sin(currentTime*2) + 1) / 4
        WIDTH = 5000 * x
        rebuild()
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, I got the same results.

Comment: oops i meant to mean that *both* uses of SKShapeNode -- the mask and the red background -- would suffer the same fate. updating answer with running example.

Comment: Your new code doesn't illustrate a solution.  It is different from the code in the problem and illustrates something else.  Using an SKSpriteNode as redRect in the original code doesn't solve the problem either.